# How to hear/view files with extensions .VOB, .IFO, and .BUP on a Mac

Tags: file-conversion

A friend of mine just got a new MacBook and is trying to look at some files she had from her old Wintel boxen with .VOB, .IFO, and .BUP file extensions.  What Mac conversion or viewing utility or app should be used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm fairly sure these are files from a DVD movie disc.

Open the default DVD player app, choice, `File` > `Open DVD Media` and select the folder in which the files are located (not the file itself, the app will combine them all and if all goes well, play the movie).

Comment: VLC can also play them

Comment: Probably these are from/for a video CD, whereas a DVD would have a VIDEO_TS folder.  Anyway, as you say, DVD Player should play this.

Answer (score 1):

As seen on [this forum](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=293474), both VLC media player and Apple's own DVD Player should do the job. In VLC, just click "Open Disc" instead of "File" while in VLC (DVD Player: File -> Open media -> VIDEO_TS folder), and select the Video_TS folder.

You can see all of the features of VLC as well as all file extensions supported by it on the [VLC Home Page](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html).

Answer (score -4):

Insert the DVD and open Macintosh HD and Applications and DVDplayer.app, the dvd will start playing.